# How can I display greek symbols in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How can I use the degree symbol when writing a GUI in Matlab? I can use `^\circ` when plotting but this does not work when writing a GUI.

This is my GUI so far:

```
directory = 'Data';
SiteName = 'AAA';
done = false;
spcFrac = 2; %number of spaces = char;
num2delim = 20;
defSlt = 'aTemp';
loader = 'on';

fclose all;
outputOptions = {'Air temperature','aTemp'};
defaults = {'',''};
% long names for outputs
names    = {'latitude (deg N)','altitude (m)'};
lines = [4,5];
[~,b] = sortrows(outputOptions); vL = length(b);
outN = cell(vL,1);outA = outN;outUn = outN;
for k = 1:length(b)
    outUn{k}= outputOptions{b(k),1};
    outN{k} = outputOptions{b(k),1};
    outA{k} = outputOptions{b(k),2};
end

indx = strcmp(defSlt,outA);
slt{1} = outN{indx};
txt = outA{indx};
outN(indx) = [];

close all
bckColor = [.85 .85 .85];
figDims = [150 150 400 300];
lM = 15;
tM = 20;
rM = 15;
bM = 15;
pnS = 12;
bgPw = 180;
bgPh = 120;
btnH = 25;
txtH = 20;
txtW = 40;
txtS = 5;
spc = 9;
radioW = 150;
radioH = 20;

bigPanels(1,:) = [lM figDims(4)-bgPh-tM bgPw bgPh];
bigPanels(2,:) = bigPanels(1,:); bigPanels(2,1) = bigPanels(2,1)+pnS+bgPw;
filePanel = [bigPanels(2,1)+bgPw+pnS*2 bM+pnS+btnH ...
    figDims(3)-bgPw*2-lM-pnS*3-rM figDims(4)-tM-pnS-btnH-bM];
btns(1,:) = [lM bigPanels(1,2)-spc-btnH bgPw btnH];
btns(2,:) = [bigPanels(2,1) bigPanels(1,2)-spc-btnH bgPw btnH];
btns(3,:) = [filePanel(1)+filePanel(3)-bgPw bM bgPw btnH];
btns(4,:) = [filePanel(1) bM radioW radioH];

numTxtIn = numel(defaults);
rowsTxt = ceil(numTxtIn/2);
for p = 1:rowsTxt
    txtBoxL(p,:) = [lM bM+(p-1)*(pnS+txtH) txtW txtH];

    txtBoxR(p,:) = [lM+pnS+bgPw bM+(p-1)*(pnS+txtH) txtW txtH ];
    diaL(p,:) = [lM+txtW+txtS -txtS+bM+(p-1)*(pnS+txtH) txtBoxR(p,1)-...
        lM-txtW-pnS txtH ];
    diaR(p,:) = [txtBoxR(p,1)+txtW+txtS -txtS+bM+(p-1)*(pnS+txtH) ...
        txtBoxR(p,1)-lM-txtW-pnS txtH ];
end
S.fh = figure('units','pixels',...
              'position',figDims,...
              'menubar','none',...
              'resize','off',...
              'numbertitle','off',...
              'name','Configuration File','Color',bckColor);
          movegui(S.fh,'center')
outFrame=uipanel('Parent',S.fh,'BackgroundColor',bckColor,...
        'Title','Output options','FontSize',10);
        setpixelposition(outFrame,[lM-spc btns(1,2)-spc ...
        bgPw+spc*2 bgPh+btnH+spc*3+pnS]);

slcFrame=uipanel('Parent',S.fh,'BackgroundColor',bckColor,...
        'Title','Output selections','FontSize',10);
        setpixelposition(slcFrame,[bigPanels(2,1)-spc btns(1,2)-spc ...
        bgPw+spc*2 bgPh+btnH+spc*3+pnS]);
ParamFrame=uipanel('Parent',S.fh,'BackgroundColor',bckColor,...
        'Title','User parameters','FontSize',10);
        setpixelposition(ParamFrame,[btns(1,1)-spc ...
            bM-spc bgPw*2+pnS+spc*2 btns(1,2)-2*spc-2]);

for lm = 1:rowsTxt
    indr = rowsTxt-lm+1;
S.outT(1,indr) = uicontrol('style','edit',...
    'units','pix',...
    'position',txtBoxL(indr,:),...
    'HorizontalAlign','center',...
    'string','Remove',...
    'fontsize',8,'String',defaults{lm,1},...
    'callback',{@txt_call,lines(lm,1)},...
    'BackgroundColor','w');
S.outT(2,indr) = uicontrol('style','edit',...
    'units','pix',...
    'position',txtBoxR(indr,:),...
    'HorizontalAlign','center',...
    'string','Remove',...
    'fontsize',8,'String',defaults{lm,2},...
    'callback',{@txt_call,lines(lm,2)}...
    ,'BackgroundColor','w');
S.outD(1,indr) = uicontrol('style','text',...
    'units','pix',...
    'position',diaL(indr,:),...
    'HorizontalAlign','left',...
    'string','Remove',...
    'fontsize',8,'String',names{lm,1},'BackgroundColor',bckColor);
S.outD(2,indr) = uicontrol('style','text',...
    'units','pix',...
    'position',diaR(indr,:),...
    'HorizontalAlign','left',...
    'string','Remove',...
    'fontsize',8,'String',names{lm,2},'BackgroundColor',bckColor);
end
```

[image]

Here I would like to change degN into the degree symbol ^\circ does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the symbols you want to use, you can use either extended ascii or unicode symbols. So, for instance, ^\circ is `Alt+0176` which gives you `°` (numbers must be typed on keypad and the zero is necessary). `µ` is `Alt+0181`, etc. If that doesn't work, you can also programmatically use `char()`. So `char(176)` will give you the degree sign.

I should add that the `Alt+0XXX` construct is a MS Windows (it's worked as far back as 95 AFAIK) shortcut. I am certain-ish that there are similar keyboard shortcuts for MacOS and your favorite flavor of *nix. The `char` command works everywhere.

From your example code above, you just need to change the definition of `names`:

```
names    = {'latitude (°N)','altitude (m)'};
```

or

```
names    = {['latitude (' char(179) 'N)'],'altitude (m)'};
```

Comment: I have chart next to my computer that I made in Excel that has all the character codes up to 255 for quick reference. If you use Windows, the character map (under `Accessories|System Tools`) is your friend.

Comment: I think the problem with the way that I've done it is that it hasn't been written in the most sophisticated of ways. Example of my attempt is above.

Comment: And I know this does not answer your specific question, but Unicode tables are typically in hexidecimal, so if you want to go higher than extended ASCII, use `hex2dec` as in `['c = ' char(hex2dec('03BB')) char(hex2dec('03BD'))]` to get `c = λν`